# How to refer to installed files in a script in a Debian package?

Tags: linux, debian

I wish to package some R scripts and data in a Debian package.

Lets call the scripts as  script-1.R, script-2.R and script-main.R

The data is called mydata.csv.

Currently my folder structure is:

```
SRC/script-1.R
SRC/script-2.R
SRC/script-main.R
DATA/mydata.csv
```

script-main.R refers to script-1.R, script-2.R and mydata.csv.

My debian/install file will be something like:

```
/SRC/script-1.R /usr/bin
/SRC/script-2.R /usr/bin
/SRC/script-main.R /usr/bin
/DOC/mydata.csv /usr/bin
```

My query is: How do I refer to script-1.R and script-2.R and mydata.csv from script-main.R so that I can run my package ***both*** prior to packaging and ***after*** installing the package?

Also what should be the right folder for the script-1.R, script-2.R and mydata.csv in a Debian Linux Filesystem Heirarchy Standard?

The right directory for data should perhaps be: /usr/share/<package-name>/

I read this in Page 28 of : [this document](https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf)

I found my answer on [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-a-basic-debian-package-927be001ad80#e9f1) link.

The author mimics the /usr/bin and /usr/share/<package-name> directories in the debian package. I guess we ***have*** to follow this convention and ***not*** create folders like SRC or DATA which are not a part of the linux FHS.

I have a similar but different query now. The bash completion script for a package is stored in the debian folder. How can I refer to a txt file in the /usr/share/<package-name> folder from the bash completion script? I could hard code the /usr/share/<package-name>/database-for-bash-completion.txt in the bash completion script, but is there not a better way which will work for ***both*** prior and after packaging?